# Is there an event when the background changes?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I would like to create a background process that runs something every time the desktop background is changed. I can't find an NSNotification that fires this, am I just looking in the wrong places?

Comment: I do not know, whether you look at the wrong places, because you did not tell on which places you looked. Did you check all distributed notification centers for all notifications?

Comment: This would all but certainly come from `NSWorkspace`, and I'm pretty sure there is no such notification.